# Generic overloading operator

Tags: c++, generics, operator-overloading, c++14, c++17

I like to play with auto and decltype, and then I wondered if it would be possible to do generic operators with auto. Indeed, since c++14 et can do this:

```
decltype(auto) add(auto v1, auto v2) {
  return v1 + v2;
}
```

however, I wanted to try it with templated classes containing values like this one:

```
template<typename T>
class test {
 public:
  T value;
  test(T val) {
    value = val;
  }
};
```

and then I would need an overloading operator + like this one which work:

```
template<typename T>
T operator+(test<T> const& t1, test<T> const& t2) {
    return t1.value + t2.value;
}
```

which is already quite great. However, I would like a generic operator+ which can be use by multiple classes. Like these one:

```
decltype(t1.value) operator+(auto const& t1, auto const& t2) {
    return t1.value + t2.value;
}

template<typename T>
T operator+(auto const& t1, auto const& t2) {
    return t1.value + t2.value;
}
```

which doesn't not compile.

In C++14/17, is there a way to make generics overloading operators which would be able to be used by many classes like the ones I wrote ?

PS: here the code for your tests which compile with gcc7 snapshot but not with clang which seems to don't allow the auto in functions prototypes :
[link to compiler explorer code](https://godbolt.org/g/4iTIb5)

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class test {
 public:
  T value;
  test(T val) {
    value = val;
  }
};

template<typename T>
T operator+(test<T> const& t1, test<T> const& t2) {
    return t1.value + t2.value;
}

decltype(auto) add(auto v1, auto v2) {
  return v1 + v2;
}

int main() {
  decltype(5) v1 = 5;
  decltype(v1) v2 = 3;
  test<decltype(v1)> t(v1);
  test<decltype(v2)> t2(v2);

  return add(t, t2);
}
```

Comment: "*Indeed, since c++14 et can do this:*" No, you can't. `auto` can only be used as parameter placeholders in *lambdas*. It's Concepts TS that extends it to regular functions. And C++14 doesn't include that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question, you can use a trailing return type:

```
auto operator+(auto const& t1, auto const& t2) -> decltype(t1.value + t2.value) {
    return t1.value + t2.value;
}
```

For compiler that do not accept `auto` for parameters, you can simply fall backs to two template parameters:

```
template <typename U, typename V>
auto operator+(U const& t1, V const& t2) -> decltype(t1.value + t2.value) {
    return t1.value + t2.value;
}
```

As [@Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42) mentioned in the comments, you probably want to use `decltype(t1.value + t2.value)` instead of `decltype(t1.value)` to handle conversions and promotions correctly.

Comment: gcc won't accept auto as a parameter type of a normal function if you compile with -pedantic. I would suggest that it's non-standard in this case.

Comment: @RichardHodges You're probably right (I did not know this was possible before seeing that question actually... ), I proposed an alternative that does not use auto as a parameter type.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't try with an auto in return sorry.

Comment: BTW, you probably want `decltype(t1.value + t2.value)` instead of `decltype(t1.value)` to handle promotion and other possible conversions.

Comment: @Jarod42 This would probably be better yes, but I simply followed OP's code. Will update the answer.

Comment: by adding decltype(t1.value + t2.value) I worried if the compiler would be able to understand to result of something it didn't calculate yet so that's why I chose to do only decltype(t1.value). thanks to make me know it's possible.